# I'm using foundation, and I don't know why my header isn't centered correctly

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm pretty bad at CSS, but here is the page I'm working on: https://www.aeonvera.com/

I'm using Foundation 5.

The markup for the header and subheader look like this:

```
.imageoverlay.text-center.panel.bg-header
    h1.text-center = APPLICATION_CONFIG["app_name"]
    h6.subheader.text-center Event registration designed for dancers.
```

(^ Slim Templating)

So.. I don't know why it's not centered. It might be possible that something else is messing with the centering? perhaps a width? idk. Super confusion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this because of this rule `.panel` try to set it like so and it will be centered like you expect it :

```
.panel { padding: 7.25rem; }
```

Comment: that fixed it! how did you know how much `rem` to pad with?

Comment: You can use rem to scale some elements in a document while leaving others in place, so I do experimenting with it  to much the center :)

Answer (score 0):

add `padding-right: 95px;` to `text-center` class